# How to use library with different version then one bundled with Android?

Tags: java, android, versioning, libraries

I want to use the latest HttpClient 4.1 version in my application. But Android already bundled with HttpClient.

The only way that I see is to build this library from sources, and change package name.

Is there any other solution?

**EDIT:**

At [download page](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) I see OSGi bundle. I have no experience in using OSGi, but AFAIK, OSGi intended to solve libraries versioning problems? If so, how can I use it?

Comment: [This guy has done it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577035/68805)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Maven Shade Plugin to move all classes to a different package and then use it from there. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

If you do that the easiest will be to also build you application with Maven using the Maven Android Plugin http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/

Comment: I haven't been able to get the maven-shade-plugin and the android-maven-plugin (new name of the maven-android-plugin) to properly work together. There is some talk about a related patch for the android-maven-plugin (https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=170), but as far as I can tell this never made into a mainline/released version. 
Were you able to get it working? And if so, can you provide some sample pom.xml code? Thanks.

Comment: I never needed it myself. Worst case you can do the shading of a jar in a separate project and then depend on that shaded jar. This will definitely work.