# Good idea to include JAR files in Android library (potential conflict with other libraries)?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, conflict

My Android library requires some of the newer Apache HTTPClient jar files so that I can upload a multipart file ([See related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220954/276949))

I'm pretty sure there will be some apps out there using my library with a different version of these Apache JAR files already, resulting in a conflict.

I've seen this happen quite a few times with `android-support-v4.jar` and third-party libraries. Is there any best-practice work-around, or should I implement multipart uploading from scratch?

Comment: might be worth looking at `gradle` http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

Comment: @pjco, what specific feature of Gradle resolves this problem? I'm reading the spec but I don't see anything about resolving library conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repackage the apache http client so that it uses a new package name so that it does not conflict with any other versions on the classpath.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061987/how-to-use-library-with-different-version-then-one-bundled-with-android) explains how to do it with the [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/),

This [article](http://priyanka-tyagi.blogspot.ca/2013/03/dealing-with-java-hell-using-jarjar.html) explains how to do it with [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) and ant.

Comment: Doesn't repackaging the apache http client tie all your users to that version? In the sense that your lib will possibly stuck on older versions and duplicate versions.  Unless you absolutely need something specific, this seems inflexible.  I would imagine the right way to do this is via `maven` or `gradle`, no?  (deleted previous confusing comment I made, appologies)

Comment: @pjco This is the versioning problem.  On one hand you want to use a version of the library shared by the rest of the system to get updates, reduce size, but on the other hand you want to use a fixed version of a library because you know your code works with it.  These are both good goals to have, but you can only satisfy one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/). Basically the author created a script to change the package name (so it doesn't conflict with the Android version) and remove some functionality (due to dependencies on org.ietf.jgss).

Script can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/source/browse/script/convert_stock_httpclient).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that best practice would be building your library as a Maven project with dependencies. Most libraries today are provided that way and it also lets you automatically generate jars with dependencies either included or not.

See for instance dagger-compiler at http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cdagger-compiler
which has both a jar without dependencies included and a jar-with-dependencies